# Social-auth-app-django (Login with LinkedIn), user not getting authenticated

Tags: django, python-social-auth, django-socialauth

I'm successfully able to fetch all the user details from LinkedIn into the database and a new user is being created every time. How to 'login' the created user?

These are the packages installed in my virtual enviornment:

```
certifi==2018.4.16
chardet==3.0.4
defusedxml==0.5.0
Django==1.10.8
idna==2.7
oauthlib==2.1.0
pkg-resources==0.0.0
PyJWT==1.6.4
python-social-auth==0.3.6
python3-openid==3.1.0
requests==2.19.1
requests-oauthlib==1.0.0
six==1.11.0
social-auth-app-django==2.1.0
social-auth-core==1.7.0
urllib3==1.23
```

These are the changes I made in my 'settings.py':

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'accounts',
    'social_django',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    ]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'social_django.middleware.SocialAuthExceptionMiddleware',
    ]

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                'social_django.context_processors.backends',
                'social_django.context_processors.login_redirect',
            ],
        },
    },
]

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'social.backends.linkedin.LinkedinOAuth2',
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
)

SOCIAL_AUTH_LINKEDIN_OAUTH2_KEY = 'my_key'
SOCIAL_AUTH_LINKEDIN_OAUTH2_SECRET = 'my_secret'

SOCIAL_AUTH_LINKEDIN_OAUTH2_SCOPE =     ['r_basicprofile','r_emailaddress']
SOCIAL_AUTH_LINKEDIN_OAUTH2_FIELD_SELECTORS = ['email-address']
SOCIAL_AUTH_LINKEDIN_OAUTH2_EXTRA_DATA = [('id', 'id'),
                               ('firstName', 'first_name'),
                               ('lastName', 'last_name'),
                               ('emailAddress', 'email_address')]

SOCIAL_AUTH_LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/home/'
SOCIAL_AUTH_LOGIN_URL = '/'
```

This is my main 'urls.py':

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^', include('accounts.urls')),
    url(r'', include('social_django.urls', namespace='social')),
]
```

This is another 'urls.py' inside 'accounts' app:

```
from django.conf.urls import url,include
from . import views

urlpatterns=[
    url(r'^$', views.login, name='login'),
    url(r'^home/$',views.home, name='home'),
]
```

And this is my 'views.py':

```
from django.shortcuts import render,redirect

def login(request):
    return render(request,'login.html')

def home(request):
    print(request.user)
    print(request.user.is_authenticated())
    return render(request,'home.html')
```

My 'login.html' only has one line:

```
<a href="{% url 'social:begin' backend='linkedin-oauth2' %}">Login with Linkedin</a>
```

Now, after clicking on 'Login with LinkedIn' and giving the website permission to access user profile the user is redirected to 'home' view and the two print statements produces the following output:

```
AnonymousUser
False
```

This is the screenshot of my [database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mKLyD.png).

The user data is successfully saved in the database, but the user is not actually logged in. Can anyone tell me how to do that?

Comment: Are the users marked as `is_active` in the database?

Comment: @omab Yes, they are marked as `is_active` in the database.

Comment: could you add a setting for `LOGIN_ERROR_URL` and point it to some place? That will tell you if the auth process is success or failing, but since you just have `LOGIN_URL`, that can be confusing.

Comment: @omab I have also added the screenshot of my database in the question now.

Comment: @omab I added  `SOCIAL_AUTH_LOGIN_ERROR_URL = '/error/'` to my settings.py and created a view for this URL, but it's still being redirected to `/home/` and not to `/error/`.

Comment: then I would recommend to debug what's going on on this function https://github.com/python-social-auth/social-app-django/blob/master/social_django/views.py#L94, that's the one responsible for logging in the user.

Comment: @omab I was already going through that function couple of minutes ago. Can you tell me if this is can happen because of any dependency issues? I have also mentioned the packages installed in my environment. I installed both `social-auth-app-django` and `python-social-auth`.

Comment: I don't think this is because dependencies, I don't see anything on them that also involve the user session or user handling upon login. As for `python-social-auth`, you can drop that one since it's deprecated, but shouldn't affect you since it's not in the installed apps setting.

Comment: @omab I didn't install `python-social-auth` earlier as I was following the documentation but then upon clicking `login with LinkedIn` link, Django was giving error `'social' : module not found`. Then I installed `python-social-auth` and suddenly error was gone. I don't know how and why that happened.

Comment: If that's the case, then social-auth wasn't properly installed, the module `social` is not used anymore, we have dedicated modules `social_core`, `social_django`, etc. And the package `python-social-auth` is deprecated.

Comment: If that's the case, then social-auth wasn't properly installed, the module `social` is not used anymore, we have dedicated modules `social_core`, `social_django`, etc. And the package `python-social-auth` is deprecated.

Comment: @omab I found the bug! I wrote `social.backends.linkedin.LinkedinOAuth2` in AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS, but it was supposed to be `social_core.backends.linkedin.LinkedinOAuth2`. Now it's working absolutely fine!

Comment: This post is a bit back but I am getting a problem to set redirect url in Linkedin. I tried http://localhost:8000/oauth/complete/linkedin-oauth2/ but it is not working. oauth is the namespace. What is the right url setting in this case?

Comment: @Gene9y Did you try http://localhost:8000/complete/linkedin-oauth2/ ?

Comment: Suddenly works. I used the link with oauth-namespace localhost:8000/oauth/complete/linkedin-oauth2.. Many thanks!